# Using WSO2 to call a local API

Tags: docker, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I ran a WSO2 service using docker and I followed all instructions according to the WSO2's document and everything worked fine including it's own Hello-world API. Next I have created my own Hello World API on my local machine on port `:8082`. I have set both Production Endpoint and Sanbox Endpoint to `http://localhost:8082` but everytime I try to test the api it gives the following error:

```
    
Failed to fetch.
Possible Reasons:

CORS
Network Failure
URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
```

Update:
I replaced `localhost` with my machine IP and used `netcat` on my local and `telnet` on the container to check it and it was okay. I don't know what is my next step.
Is there anything specific that I should consider for developing my Hello World that I'm missing?

Comment: When you use the hostname, you should have the proper certificates configured/imported to the trust store. Please try after importing the certificate of Endpoint to the trust store of the APIm image and you will be good.

Comment: Could you explain this in detail? Thank you in advance @PrabakaranThodithotSembiyan

Comment: Does the curl command which shows in the tryout work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume both your API GW and Backend API run with the same hostname, which creates SSL failure, so I recommend you create a new key store for your backend and export the key store as a certificate and import it into the trust store of API GW.

```
keytool -keystore backend.jks -genkey -alias backend 
keytool -export -keystore backend.jks -alias backend -file backend.crt
keytool -import -file backend.crt -alias backend -keystore <APIM_HOME>/repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks
```

This enables the Gateway to trust the backend server (host) and enables you to communicate seamlessly.

Thanks.